# Failed to Read Artifact Descriptor: IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am running into an issue with my Maven POM file where its unable to find spark dependency and is returning with error:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:jar:1.2.1

I've confirmed its not an issue with any corporate firewall as every other dependency is loaded in properly, just this one.

I have also been able to confirm in my maven settings it is attempting to pull from the following repo.  I tried deleting the .m2 repo on my local machine in order to reload it, still no dice.

http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10/1.2.1/

Attached below is my pom file

```
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>sentiment</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>NPITWITTER</name>

    <properties>
    </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sparkjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

Comment: This dependency correctly exists: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10/1.2.1 so the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Resolved it, was due to a proxy setting that was enabled. Re-ran with `mvn -U clean install` and all was repaired.

Comment: indeed, it was proxy related setting.

Answer (score 117):

In Intellij, I had the same issue,

I did the proxy settings also, and ran the command `mvn –U clean install` but it's **not working.**

I got its resolved with the below setting enabled (highlighted in yellow)

In Intellij, go to **File** -> **Settings** -> **Build, Execution, Deployments** -> **Maven**
Check the box, ‘**Always update snapshots**’

[image: Intellij Settings window snapshot]

Comment: Worked for me as it seems to have forced to download all the dependencies of all the sub-projects.

Comment: That's 'IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences' on Mac

Comment: Was helpful with the same issue appeared in one project after updating to 2018.2.2

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy i was about to leave intelli J IDEA, you saved my night.

Comment: I also need to tick the  `use plugin registry` tab and it works then.

Comment: In case none of these work for you go to your apache-maven-<version>/conf folder and check your settings.xml, mine had proxy settings in them messing things up.

Answer (score 6):

Following worked for IDEA 17,

- Go to `File`
- Select `Settings`
- Select `Build, Execution, Deployments`
- Select `Build Tools` from drop down
- Select `Maven` from drop down
- Tick the `Always update snapshots` check box

Comment: Your answer just saved me hours, if not days

Answer (score 6):

I guess IntelliJ comes with and ambedded Maven installation, so just make sure your IDE is pointing to the right **Maven home directory:** and **User settings file:** values, these are under:

- Go to `File`
- Select `Settings`
- Select `Build, Execution, Deployments`
- Select `Build Tools` from drop down
- Select `Maven` from drop down

Answer (score 2):

I had just solved the issue. Please, go in the Maven tab of the `Build, Execution, Deployments` and set it to the settings provided.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The above solution had to extend further to resolve my issue(In IntelliJ idea).

**Step 1**
Go to `File -> Settings -> (Build, Execution, Deployment) -> Maven` and *tick* the `Always update snapshot` option and then click on `Apply -> Ok`
[image]

**Step 2**

Go to `File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart` 
[image]

**Step 3**

Build the project after step 2 and see whether the error is fixed. If not, `Restart` the computer and then run the project.

***I had to follow all the 3 steps to get the error fixed***

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was proxy related problem. I am highlighting few of areas where you may need to verify and correct the same.

1. Intellij proxy settings from preference window
2. maven settings.xml entry from your ~/.m2/settings.xml or /usr/local/Cellar/maven//libexec/conf/settings.xml
3. System proxy

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

Go to file => Settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => Maven => Maven home directory: change from Bundled (Maven 3) to **Bundled (Maven 2)**