# Intellij Maven Repository self signed certificate, ssl error

Tags: maven, ssl, repository, intellij-15

In intellij (15.0.4) under settings->Maven->Repositories I get an error when clicking update on the companies repositories.

org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I can understand, since it is a self-signed untrusted certificate, however, I have added this certificate to
settings->Tools->Server Certificates->Accepted Certificates.

I also added to settings->Maven->Runner->VM Options 
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true

I still get this problem.

Greatful for a solution.

Comment: Adding the two VM Options to Maven Runner solved it for me (thanks for this!). No need to add the certificate to Server Certificates.
IntelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 2016.3.4

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Update both Maven Importer and Runner in settings to allow all.

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

Runner

[image]

Importer

[image]

Comment: it solved my problem too, earlier i was just updating this in maven > importing. Putting the vm option command in Runner too did the trick.

Comment: I get "Failed to read artifact descriptor for xxx:jar:0.1.0" after I entered these in VM Options for imported.
This helped https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105667/failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor-intellij/44715063

Comment: Great, Thanks for the answer. It saves my day.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the settings mentioned above did not work. I put the both in the Runner and Importing sections:

```
-Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

The solution was to use **DNS name** instead of IP address in repositories.repository.url of the pom file

Not working:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ci-my-nexus</id>
        <name>My Nexus</name>
        <url>https://172.31.34.45/repository/my-maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Working (mind the `url` part):

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>ci-my-nexus</id>
        <name>My Nexus</name>
        <url>https://artifacts.mycompany.com/repository/my-maven/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```