# Importing Apache Velocity in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, apache-velocity

I am using the IntelliJ IDEA on a mac and want to import Apache Velocity. In my pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.velocity/velocity -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am getting the error

`Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.velocity:jar:1.7`

Are there other settings that I need to add?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please check the logs for errors, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/42427510/104891.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105667/failed-to-read-artifact-descriptor-intellij

Answer (score 0):

It is a fresh install of Itellij Idea and I had to set the following:

```
IntelliJ Idea -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> 
Build Tools -> Maven -> Always update snapshots -> Apply -> Ok
```

Of course you can just download the [jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.velocity%22%20AND%20a%3A%22velocity%22) file and import it as a module instead.